# PHP file_get_html() $html->find('a') not working for certain URL

Tags: php

For some reason, this link doesn't work, but the other one does. I tried expanding the size, and it seemed to max out~ I don't see where it could be looping infinitely :S.

The error said:
Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on boolean in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/simplehtmldom_1_5/example/test.php on line 7

Doesn't work:

```
<?php

include('../simple_html_dom.php');

$html = file_get_html('http://www.watchepisodes4.com/the-flash');

foreach($html->find('a') as $e) {
    echo $e->href . '<br>';
}

?>
```

Works:

```
<?php

include('../simple_html_dom.php');

$html = file_get_html('http://www.watchepisodes4.com');

foreach($html->find('a') as $e) {
    echo $e->href . '<br>';
}

?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Did you check if there were errors? Did you check what html is returned to you?

Comment: Sorry forgot to include that! It said: Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on boolean in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/simplehtmldom_1_5/example/test.php on line 7

Comment: Did you try to read documentation on `file_get_html`? Looks like you got `false` back. An I can guarantee there should be the way to see actual error in this documentation too.

Comment: I did get false back when I tested it with var_dump($html), which gave me bool(false). I am not sure how to see it in the documentation, thanks for ur help so far!

Comment: check errors in your error log. It just does not download content for some reason. And you probably need to stop using library that is unmaintained since 2014.

Comment: https://github.com/paquettg/php-html-parser or http://htmlparsing.com/php.html

Comment: Hmmm, Ive been trying to find an error log but I couldn't find it. I am not sure where to go from here :(